# Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged - does a better way exist without using AOP?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, inotifypropertychanged, c#-6.0

My question is a sub-question of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist).

The author is asking:

> Microsoft should have implemented something snappy for
>   INotifyPropertyChanged, like in the automatic properties, just specify
>   {get; set; notify;} I think it makes a lot of sense to do it. Or are
>   there any complications to do it?
>
> Can we ourselves implement something like 'notify' in our properties.
>   Is there a graceful solution for implementing INotifyPropertyChanged
>   in your class or the only way to do it is by raising the
>   PropertyChanged event in each property.
>
> If not can we write something to auto-generate the piece of code to
>   raise PropertyChanged event?

My question is, is there something we can do that is even simpler than:

`{get;set;notify;}` ?

How about just:

```
{get;set;} ?
```

Is there a way to make it more implicit? We have applications where changes to every property always need to be tracked.

Comment: very good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist

Comment: No, without some form of code generation, there is no better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code generation i know only one solution - use Castle Dynamic Proxy and interceptor as described here: http://jonas.follesoe.no/oldblog/2009-12-23-automatic-inotifypropertychanged-using-dynamic-proxy/